# Implementing multifile upload from stratch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I want to implement a multi file upload function for my website. When I googled for tutorials on it, I found many plugins but nothing which can guide me about how to develop it from scratch. The project I am working on is for my learning purpose so I don't want to use any plug in. I can use I frames but flash is again not a choice for me. Can anyone help. I want some brief steps of it. Thankx.

PS. I know how to develop its back end. I want to implement its front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start with a single `<input type="file" name="file" />` field.
2. Then, to make it multiple, add a javascript function, which dynamically creates fields and add them into the page.
3. Than, to make upload without reloading page, put it all in the iframe.

Comment: But in input file method, Users are not allowed to select multiple files selecting with ctrl key pressed. How can I enable it?

Comment: <input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" />